# Tomcat7 and session

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7

I have problem with Tomcat7 and my app.

I would create a bean and set a property. I would use the same property in another jsp(get)
without recreate the bean. I declared the bean with the scope "session" but when I try to get the property, it is null. why? what do I wrong?

In my webapp I have:

test1.jsp

```
call test2.jsp and pass the parameter "name"="mm"
```

test2.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="sBean" scope="session" class="my.package.SessionBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="sBean" property="*" />
```

The value of property "name" is corectly "mm"

test3.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="sBean" scope="session" class="my.package.SessionBean" />
<% sBean.getName() %>
```

The value of property "name" is NULL, instead of "mm"

```
public Sessionbean implements Serializable
{
  private String name;
  public SessionBean(){}
  //get and set of name
}
```

The same thing in tomcat6 works perfectly

Comment: Make the question more clear......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works in tomcat6 and not tomcat7, but I think if you change in test3.jsp:

```
<% sBean.getName() %>
```

to:

```
<% SessionBean testBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("sBean"); //try changing name of SessionBean too so it doesn't conflict with the useBean name
   testBean.getName();
%>
```

It should work.  Alternatively, you could use:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="sBean" property="name" />
```

**Update**
I put together two JSP pages.  I tested it quickly in tomcat 7 and it worked for me.  I didn't do a form though, but I think this is the general idea.  Is that roughly how you have it setup?

test1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="my.project.SessionBean" %>
<jsp:useBean id="sBean" scope="session" class="my.project.SessionBean" />


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
SessionBean testBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("sBean");
testBean.setName("Nate");
pageContext.forward("test2.jsp"); //forward to test2.jsp after setting name

%>
<jsp:getProperty name="sBean" property="name" />

</body>
</html>
```

test2.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<jsp:useBean id="sBean" scope="session" class="my.project.SessionBean" />
<%@ page import="my.project.SessionBean" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>page 2</p>
<p>from jsp tag</p>
<jsp:getProperty name="sBean" property="name" /><br />

<p> from scriptlet</p>
<%
SessionBean testBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("sBean");
out.print(testBean.getName());
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: with <% SessionBean sBean = (SessionBean) //etc
I get sBean=null. why?

Comment: Do you have <%@ page import="my.package.SessionBean" %> at the top of the JSP?  Can you post a little more of your code?

Comment: I put together a quick example and also changed sBean to testBean for <% SesssionBean testBean = (SessionBean) //etc just in case it was a naming conflict, but I don't think it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original pages are almost good.
the scriptlet in test3.jsp is missing the equal sign(=). It should be  <%=sBeangetname()%>.
 
It should be the ()IS/GET)fieldname  (or pseudofielname) a public method name.
The answer containing "(SessionBean) session.getAttribute("sBean")" works. BUT it does not use the bean mechanism includes in JSP. Thus, it's wrong.